# chef-run vs chef under systemd - different gem repos

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to make chef swap the official rubygems repo with my own local one. It kind of does work but let's say 'not always'. More on that below.

```
bash-4.2$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```

Chef is running under control of systemd. When I check in journal what chef has done so far I get

```
Jan 14 07:39:24 myserver.srv chef-client[32274]: [2016-01-14T07:39:24+01:00] INFO: Processing execute[add_my_own_repo] action run (mycookbook::gem line 5)
Jan 14 07:39:24 myserver.srv chef-client[32274]: [2016-01-14T07:39:24+01:00] INFO: Processing execute[Guard resource] action run (dynamically defined)
Jan 14 07:39:24 myserver.srv chef-client[32274]: [2016-01-14T07:39:24+01:00] INFO: execute[Guard resource] ran successfully
Jan 14 07:39:24 myserver.srv chef-client[32274]: [2016-01-14T07:39:24+01:00] INFO: Processing execute[del_official_https_rubygems_repo] action run (mycookbook::gem line 10)
Jan 14 07:39:24 myserver.srv chef-client[32274]: [2016-01-14T07:39:24+01:00] INFO: Processing execute[Guard resource] action run (dynamically defined)
```

The code of my recipe mycookbook::gem is as follows

```
execute 'add_my_own_repo' do
  command '/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --add http://myrepo'
  not_if '/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --list | grep myrepo'
end.run_action(:run)

execute 'del_official_https_rubygems_repo' do
  command '/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --remove  https://rubygems.org/'
  only_if '/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --list | grep https://rubygems.org'
end.run_action(:run)
```

If I check the list of gem sources again I'll get

```
bash-4.2$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```

Unfortunately nothing has changed so far. Now, if I run chef-client directly from the console I finally see chef doing what I wanted to be done.

```
Recipe: mycookbook::gem
  * execute[add_my_own_repo] action run
   - execute /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --add http://myrepo
  * execute[del_official_https_rubygems_repo] action run
    - execute /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --remove  https://rubygems.org/
```

When I turned on debug mode I noticed chef claiming the condition was not met

```
DEBUG: Skipping execute[del_official_https_rubygems_repo] due to only_if command `gem sources --list | /usr/bin/grep https://rubygems.org`
```

Wth? I did some further investigation and in desperation added to the recipe

```
  execute 'CHEF_ENV' do
    command 'env >> /tmp/chef_env'
  end.run_action(:run)

  execute 'GEM_SOURCES' do
   command 'gem sources --list >> /tmp/chef_gem_sources'
  end.run_action(:run)
```

Now when I checked the content of /tmp/chef_gem_sources I was utterly bewildered

```
cat chef_gem_sources 
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://myrepo
```

Finally, in /tmp/chef_env I found HOME=/. It's obviously HOME=/root when I launch chef-client myself. It makes a huge difference as .gemrc has two locations and may have different values in :sources section.

Comment: Use a full path to grep, so you're sure it's not a PATH problem from parent environment PATH. I'm pretty sure a `env -i /opt/chef/bin/chef-client` would fail too.

Comment: I logged to a file the value of $PATH variable that chef-cllient has. Everything's fine. Full path to grep is not necessary.

Comment: Add -l debug in your systemd launch so you'll have more info in log. I see no reason if grep behaves properly.

Comment: In journal `chef-client[14910]: [2016-01-15T18:04:30+01:00] DEBUG: Skipping execute[del_official_https_rubygems_repo] due to only_if command /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources --list | /usr/bin/grep https://rubygems.org` then when I run it myself the condition is met...

Comment: [edit] your post, and be sure of the state before...

Comment: I always start testing with only https://rubygems.org/ in my sources...

Comment: Sorry to ask but are you using the same user as the systemd service ? (I can only think about this probability and I can't check gem source files on phone) As far as I know chef does not enforce a gem repo. But give which version you're using so we can check if there's not a glitch in the codebase. We can't guess your Env. So describe it as much as you can so we can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks for help. Inspecting environments and learning about the fact that list of gem repos is stored in .gemrc file solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. First you want to put `action :nothing` on your two execute resources so they don't happen at both compile and converge time. Second, the output differs because Chef checks if stdout is a TTY when determining the output style. If it is a TTY, you get the new formatter output, otherwise you get logger output.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Still it didn't help to make it work as it should.