# Initial read of .gemrc

Tags: chef-infra

I'm changing the address of rubygems repository from the official one to my local one as stated here

[chef-run vs chef under systemd - different gem repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784151/chef-run-vs-chef-under-systemd-different-gem-repos)

One last problem I have is that it doesn't work at chef's initial run. At first run even after it changes rubygems.org to my localrepo, all my cookbooks that want to install specific gems are trying to connect to rubygems.org and as the machine has no access to the Internet it's a bit frustrating. Is it possible to refresh it somehow right after I change the address of the ruby repo?

I'm using chef_gem method.

Comment: If this with `gem_package` or `chef_gem`?

Comment: chef_gem 'some-gem' do
  compile_time true if respond_to?(:compile_time)
end